# Windows application to set permanent cookie in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

I need to set a permanent cookie in Chrome on a PC that I won't have access to after setup. If Chrome deletes it or it expires it needs to be re-set. This is to be able to recognize traffic coming from this particular PC.

The PC in question is a PC in a nursery home where the website runs in kiosk mode, and to combat some of the limitations of kiosk mode I need to add some specific javascript code to the website.

Things I've already tried and have tried seeking help in, to no avail:

- Appending a string to the useragent using an extension (no extension available that does that)
- Detecting the kiosk mode itself (not possible)
- Detecting fullscreen mode based on window height and screen height (breaks when a user zooms in)
- Detecting based on IP (no static IP is available at the location)
- Creating a Chrome App (Chrome Apps are deprecated and won't be supported in the future)

For those reasons the only way to do this seems to be to place a cookie. However, since I don't want to have to return to the location of the PC every once a while I need the cookie to be persistent, no matter what.

It's just normal Chrome running on a Windows 10 PC. That's why I was thinking about a 3rd party application that could set and re-set a cookie for me. Any ideas?

Comment: Your best bet is to use a [Chrome extension to inject the cookie](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies).

Comment: I did look for extensions, but none could make sure the cookie would be set permanently. Do you have any suggestions? I'm not really an extension developer.

Comment: I suspect for such a specialised use-case you're going to have to write your own.

Comment: Thanks for the help, looking into it now. I would have guessed there would be some generic "make certain cookies persist" extension, but apparently not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as this is pretty much impossible with existing extensions I've decided to write a very small one myself. It simply creates a cookie that expires in 8 years when a user visits a page of the website and then resets it every hour.

I used the example files provided at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted and modified them to fit my needs.

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Hemelryck detectie",
  "description": "This extension places a persistent cookie used to detect this particular PC on the Hemelryck website",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "*://*.onsplatform.tv/",
    "cookies"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://www.onsplatform.tv/hemelryck*"],
      "js": ["addcookie.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

addcookie.js:

```
document.cookie = "ishemelryck=1; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2025 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";

setInterval(
  function(){
    document.cookie = "ishemelryck=1; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2025 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";
  }
  ,3600
);
```

Comment: I suspect your current script would wipe all existing cookies. Dunno if that's a problem for your use-case. I would suggest using the `chrome.cookies.set` function in a privileged (chrome) script instead of a content script. But I'm not too familiar with Chrome extensions myself.

Comment: It doesn't, and why would it? With `document.cookie` it's only possible to set one cookie at a time as explained in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie. Still, I'm not very knowledgeable with Chrome extensions, I tried using `chrome.cookies.set` but it told me `chrome` wasn't set. How would I add a priviledged script?

Comment: Sorry, I think I confused it with something else - your current one should work. But if you did want to use the privileged script you'd probably need to do it either in a background or event page, as noted in the [quick start](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) and shown in the [cookie example](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/cookies/).

Comment: @Bob Ah thank you! I'll definitely check that out for version 2 of my extension :)